# Problema con ArrayList en métodos

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio donde tengo que crear un sistema solar. El problema me viene que cuando voy a ejecutarlo para hace pruebas me da un error. No sé muy bien si es porque lo tengo mal planteado. Tengo que crear un método llamado bigbang() el cual tiene que crear todos los planetas y satélites. Lo que hago es crear objetos de las dos clases en el método. No sé si seria lo correcto. El error es:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.ArrayList.add(Object)" because "this.planetas" is null
at SistemaSolar/SistemaSolar.SistemaSolar.bigBang(SistemaSolar.java:31)
at SistemaSolar/Test.TestSistemaSolar.main(TestSistemaSolar.java:11)

Copio el código por si alguien me puede encaminar. Gracias.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SistemaSolar {

private Estrella estrella;
private ArrayList<Planeta> planetas;
private ArrayList<Satelite> satelites;

public SistemaSolar() {
    
}

public Estrella getEstrella() {
    return estrella;
}

public ArrayList<Planeta> getPlanetas() {
    return planetas;
}

public ArrayList<Satelite> getSatelites() {
    return satelites;
}


public void bigBang() {

      // Planetas
    planetas.add(new Planeta("Mercurio"));
    planetas.add(new Planeta("Venus"));
    planetas.add(new Planeta("Tierra"));
    planetas.add(new Planeta("Marte"));
    planetas.add(new Planeta("Júpiter"));
    planetas.add(new Planeta("Saturno"));
    planetas.add(new Planeta("Urano"));
    planetas.add(new Planeta("Neptuno"));

    // Satelites
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Luna"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Phobos"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Deimos"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Io"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Europa"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Ganímedes"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Calisto"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Titán"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Oberón"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Titania"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Umbriel"));
    satelites.add(new Satelite("Triton"));
    
     
}


public void  addPlaneta(Planeta planeta) {
    planetas.add(planeta);
    
    
}

public void addSatelite(Satelite satelite) {
    satelites.add(satelite);
}
```

}

```
public class Planeta {
    private String nombre;
    private float radioEcuatorial;
    private float temperaturaDiurna;
    private float distanciaSol;
    private float distanciaTierra;
    private ArrayList<Satelite> listaSatelites;

Planeta(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public float getRadioEcuatorial() {
    return radioEcuatorial;
}

public float getTemperaturaDiurna() {
    return temperaturaDiurna;
}

public float getDistanciaSol() {
    return distanciaSol;
}

public float getDistanciaTierra() {
    return distanciaTierra;
}

public ArrayList<Satelite> getListaSatelites() {
    return listaSatelites;
}


public  void atraparAstroEnCampoGravitarorio(Satelite satelite) {
    listaSatelites.add(satelite);
    
}

public void imprimirListaSatelites() {
    for(int i = 0; i< listaSatelites.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(listaSatelites.get(i).getNombre());
    }
}



public class Satelite {

private String nombre;
private float radio;

Satelite(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public float getRadio() {
    return radio;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList es una clase contenedora genérica que implementa arrays dinámicos de objetos de cualquier tipo.
De forma general un ArrayList en Java se crea de la siguiente forma:

```
ArrayList nombreArray = new ArrayList();
```

Te falta inicializar ambos ArrayList, puedes hacerlo en el constructor de la clase Sistema Solar

```
public SistemaSolar() {
    this.planetas=new ArrayList<>();
    this.satelites=new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```